# What is wrong with my update request ? Patch localhost undefined

Tags: mysql, angular, database, typescript

I'm working on my admin component, there is a table with a list of users account and I have the choice to accept them or delete them. They are false by default but when I click on the "Accept" button, they become true. It's working until I try to update the change in my db.

I did this
HTML :

```
 <tr *ngFor="let information of practitionerDataSource.dataSubject | async">
      <td *ngIf="practitionerDataSource.formatValue(information, 'isAccountConfirmed') == false">{{practitionerDataSource.formatValue(information, 'lastName')}}</td>
      <td *ngIf="practitionerDataSource.formatValue(information, 'isAccountConfirmed') == false">{{practitionerDataSource.formatValue(information, 'firstName')}}</td>
      <td *ngIf="practitionerDataSource.formatValue(information, 'isAccountConfirmed') == false">{{practitionerDataSource.formatValue(information, 'specialisation')}}</td>
      <td *ngIf="practitionerDataSource.formatValue(information, 'isAccountConfirmed') == false">
        <button mat-raised-button color="success"
        (click)="onSubmit()">Accepter</button>
</td>
</tr>
```

And the TS :

```
Export class SubRequestComponent implements OnInit {

  practitionerDataSource: PractitionerDataSource;
  data: IPractitioner;
  id: number;
  praticiens: IPractitioner;
  practitioner: IPractitioner;
  isAccountConfirmed = false;

  constructor(
    private practitionerService: PractitionerService,
    private dialog: MatDialog,
  ) {
  }


  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.getPractitioners();
  }

  getPractitioners() {
    this.practitionerDataSource = new PractitionerDataSource(this.practitionerService);
    this.practitionerDataSource.currentRequest = this.practitionerDataSource.loadPractitioners;
    this.practitionerDataSource.start();
  }


  onSubmit(){
    const confirmDialog = this.dialog.open(ConfirmDeleteDialogComponent, {
      data: {
        title: 'Demande d inscription',
        message: 'Etes-vous certain de vouloir refuser cette demande ?'
      }
    });
    confirmDialog.afterClosed().subscribe(result => {
      if (result) {
        this.isAccountConfirmed = true;
      }
      this.practitionerService.updateData(data).subscribe((res) => {
          if (res) {
            this.getPractitioners();
            console.log(this.isAccountConfirmed);
          }
        });
    });
  }
```

It's not working, I have a patch error, what did I do wrong ?

Comment: where is the server side that save to DB?